# Prove/disprove statement about positive sequence which tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a positive sequence. I have to verify the following statements:

> 1. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1+\frac{1}{n}$, for all but a finite number of $n$
> 2. If $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1+\frac{1}{n}$ then for all but a finite number of $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$

I think (1) is true because using Bernoulli's inequality we can get $a_n>(1+1/n)^n\geq 2$ which is of course true when $a_n$ goes to infinity. Am I correct? Also, I believe that (2) is false but for some reason I can't find a counterexample. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1): $a_n > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n \longrightarrow e$, so this must be true. So you're right about (1).

(2): False. Let $a_n = (1+\frac{2}{n})^n$. We have $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = e^2$ and $a_n > (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$.

Comment: in (2) - Is there any way showing $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \neq \infty$ without the $e$? We haven't learned about it yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd have to show that $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ converges. Then for part (2), $(1 + \frac{2}{n})^n = \left((1 + \frac{2}{n})^{n/2}\right)^2$

Comment: Thank you. What if instead of "$\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1+\frac{1}{n}$" in these statements we have "there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1+\frac{1}{k}$"?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I mean - how the answers will change if we do such a replacement?

Comment: It would become (1) False (2) True